# Пропадает звездочка в mat-form-field (required) при очень длинном mat-label

Tags: angular, angular2

```
<div class="example-container">
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="Something text" [formControl]="about" required>
    <mat-error *ngIf="about.invalid">{{getErrorMessage()}}</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можете уточнить свою проблему? Сам mat-label выступает в качестве placeholder и если он не вмещается целиком в input, то логично обрезается и поэтому текст и звездочка остается за его пределами, заменяясь троеточием. Если поле расширить или свободно изменять при `mat-form-field { width: 100%; }` то это видно. Если же проблема в чем-то другом, то уточните. Как вариант, если нужно всегда иметь в конце звездочку, можно что-то подумать с переносом здездочки в начало или mat-icon с hideRequiredMarker.

Comment: Да было бы круто что то придумать что бы звездочка была всегда, не взависимости много или мало текста для полей с (required), буду благодарен за подсказку, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Когда мы используем Material Design, мы должны понимать, что это не только графическая  библиотека. Это еще и дизайнерский гайдлайн, который говорит что и как надо использовать при проектировании интерфейса. Это накладывает на реализацию свои жесткие ограничения и условия. Что делает порой использование очень неудобным, когда нам нужно сделать шаг влево или шаг вправо от гайдлайна, но мы не хотим лезть глубоко внутрь.

Если мы посмотрим сам гайдлайн https://material.io/components/text-fields, мы увидит такие интересующие нас вещи.

1. Don't: Label text shouldn't be truncated. Keep it short, clear, and fully visible. (описание поля не должно обрезаться, делайте его коротким, понятным и полностью видимым). То есть нам сразу говорят, что длинный mat-label - это наша ошибка.
2. Для индикации обязательных полей нужно использовать не только *, но и использовать другие пояснения, поскольку сам * может ничего не говорить про обязательность.
3. Изучая примеры, мы может найти блоки из которых состоят поля и некоторые примеры решений, который можно использовать.

Какие у нас есть варианты:

- В разделе Anatomy у нас есть семь элементов у поля и в примерах мы может использовать Helper Text для подсвечивания обязательных или опциональных полей. Это является лучшим решением по гайдлайну.

  ```
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</mat-label>
      <input matInput placeholder="Something text" required>
      <mat-hint>* Required</mat-hint>
  </mat-form-field>
  ```
- Мы может использовать суффикс или префикс для таких полей, но возможно придется допиливать стили напильником, чтобы выровнить все элементы.

  ```
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill" hideRequiredMarker="hideRequiredMarker">
      <mat-label>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</mat-label>
      <input matInput placeholder="Something text" required>
      <span matSuffix>*</span>
  </mat-form-field>
  ```
- Отказаться в пользу Label для длинных описаний, но может пострадать внешний вид.

  ```
  <Label>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</Label>
  <div>
      <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
          <mat-label>Short placeholder</mat-label>
          <input matInput placeholder="Something text" required>
          <mat-hint>* Required</mat-hint>
      </mat-form-field>
  </div>
  ```
- Можем попробовать выводить звездочку перед описанием.

  ```
  .asterix--before:before {
      content: "* ";
  }

  <mat-form-field appearance="fill" hideRequiredMarker="hideRequiredMarker">
      <mat-label class="asterix--before">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</mat-label>
      <input matInput placeholder="Something text" required>
      <mat-hint>* Required</mat-hint>
  </mat-form-field>
  ```

Есть еще варианты, как с этим поступать, но все они ведут к тем или иным проблемам, поэтому я остановился на более-менее подходящих. Опять же, самый первый является наиболее правильным.

Comment: Спасибо, полезная инфа!